# Integrating facebook login and facebook c# SDK - NOT a facebook app

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I downloaded the samples and the 5.0.3 beta of the SDK, and pretty quickly got a facebook app up and running inside facebook - great and super easy.

However, I want to use facebook only as an authorization-mechanism, and I cannot figure out how to do that from the examples and documentation (actually I was unable to find any documentation apart from a few examples here and there).

I found this piece of code without context here: [Link](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=QuickStart%20using%20the%20API&referringTitle=Documentation)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!authorizer.IsAuthorized())
    {
        var authurl = authorizer.GetLoginUrl(new HttpRequestWrapper(Request));
        CanvasRedirect(authurl.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        LoggedIn(); // function to call when the user is logged in to init the page
    }
}
```

This looks really interesting, but I cannot figure out what the authorizer is set up and used.

I am using MVC 3, but that should not really matter.

Is it possible to use the facebook c# sdk for this - and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetOpenAuth CTP - Facebook bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725159/dotnetopenauth-ctp-facebook-bad-request)

The first answer there is good, with well-structured code with explanation, that I made work in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and I found my answer here maybe this will help with what you're after:  http://amirrajan.net/Blog/asp-mvc-and-facebook-single-sign-on

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you've resolved your problem, but in case somebody stumbles upon this question - I've found this new library pretty easy to understand from code:

[OAuth2Login on GitHub](https://github.com/lepipele/OAuth2Login)

Also there is pretty detailed article that explains the library:

[OAuth2 Social Logins - Facebook, Google, Twitter, PayPal - ASP.NET MVC C# open source library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006013/OAuth-Social-Logins-Facebook-Google-Twitter-PayPal)