# ASP.NET website authentication with latest v 6.0.3 facebook.dll

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

was trying to find info on the web, but wasn't found something
All I want is a "login with Facebook" example, and to get basic user information about logged in user.

as i was found here, from v6 fasebook.web.dll not supported.
on facebook c# sdk page, web site exaple page not finished.

can you please provide me with example of how to do it

Thank you very match !

Comment: Its not using facebook.dll, but if thats not important [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4300217/336182) is how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

For a webapp, you should be able to use the JavaScript API to build a login flow and get basic user info. The JavaScript API is server-side agnostic, so it'll work fine with ASP.net and C#. Take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the canvas aps.net sample mvc3 to get the idea. https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-canvas-mvc

You also always use the mixture of Facebook Javascript SDK with Facebook C# SDK.